# Are Windows 10 Store apps protected from copying/stealing/piracy etc

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Some software License Manager tools (such as [this](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) one) allow you to manage your software licenses so that your software can only be installed on one machine (using machine ID, hardware locking etc). Do `windows 10 Store Apps` have that safety from piracy of your app once it's installed from windows store?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Store will check for a valid license each time the app is launched.

For charging app or apps containing in-app-purchase product, the developer is also able to use the Store receipts API to perform additional checks. See [Using receipts to verify product purchases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases).

However, it doesn't mean that the Store will check the license automatically.

Answer (score -2):

If you think another app is infringing your intellectual property rights, please fill in this [form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?locale=EN-US&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=RAVCI&wf=0&ccsid=636128853740314945&wa=wsignin1.0) to submit a copyright, trademark or publicity rights infringement complaint on a Windows app.

For multiple apps, you could  submit your request to mktlegal@microsoft.com .

Please refer to **[Trademark and copyright protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/trademark-and-copyright-protection?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** for more information on reporting piracy.

Comment: What I'm after can be explained through this example: There are some software (such as MS Office) that have a limit of how many machines you can install on. After purchasing and installing such a software on a specified number of desktops one cannot install it on other machines. So my question is: Do Windows 10 Store Apps have that limit so that once your Store app is installed on certain # of computers you cannot install that app on other computers (beyond the number of computers you were allowed to install it on).

Comment: Note that Microsoft will completely ignore any reports about infringing or fake or misleading applications.